# Set the value of a column in a SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL I could execute the following:

```
SELECT "spam" AS "foo", "eggs" AS "bar" LIMIT 1;
```

...which would return 1 row with 2 columns ("foo" and "bar) and 2 values ("spam" and "eggs").

Is it possible to do this with TSQL in SQL Server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do any of these:

```
SELECT 'spam' foo, 'eggs' bar

SELECT 'spam' AS foo, 'eggs' AS bar

SELECT foo = 'spam', bar = 'eggs'

SELECT 'spam' "foo", 'eggs' "bar"

SELECT 'spam' [foo], 'eggs' [bar]
```

Since you're building a hard-coded set of values you don't need a limiting clause. Just FYI, the equivalent in T-SQL is `TOP`.

Comment: Ah, that was my issue; I was using double quotes `"` rather than single quotes `'` for my query. I didn't know `tsql` interprets them!

Comment: Yes, values have to be single-quoted in T-SQL.  If you use `'value'` it's implicitly a `varchar`.  If you want `nvarchar` you need to prefix the literal with `N` like this - `N'value'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TOP` to limit rows returned

```
SELECT TOP 1 'spam' AS "foo", "eggs" AS "bar"
```

But in this instance, as you are not taking the data from a table with multiple rows, you can just do:

```
SELECT 'spam' AS "foo", "eggs" AS "bar"
```

Comment: `SELECT 'spam' AS "foo"`, not `"spam"`